# Why are Android ContentProviders REST services?

Tags: android, rest, android-contentprovider

Google could have provided a JDBC API,
but chose to wrap SQLite with a REST service.
What are the benefits ?

Why are Android ContentProviders REST services ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they **abstracted away** the *data retrieval* from the *data* itself.

While for a sqlite data source, data is on the phone, you can easily implement a content provider which takes its data from a cloud service.

So you can *code against the same interface* and easily switch your data retrieval implementation.

Comment: Is this not also true for the JDBC API ? As far as I remember JDBC API is mostly Java interfaces, and then your implementation could take it's data from a cloud service.

Comment: REST gives no benefits over JDBC in this respect. IMHO this does not explain choosing REST over JDBC, since we now have to write extra code to wrap database access in a REST service.

Comment: JDBC is a database connection API. REST is much more generic.

Comment: Choosing REST will probably enable more storage solutions for Android ( SQL, OODBMS, File, Cloud )

Answer (score 1):

It's all about Ressources. A ContentProvider holds Ressources (URIs) and gives you MIME/Types of it. You can use with only 4 simple crud Methods. That's the same as using a REST-Service on HTTP. 
Very generic and simple, elegant I think.

So your App can use my ContentProvider without knowing anything about database, structure, statements - just as a REST-Service. JDBC is not as simple.